# Apache VirtualHosts does not work

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, apache-2.4

My site has one IP.
They set for me tww records into DNS servers:
www.mydomain.com    --> 
admin.mydomain.com  -->

My apache httpd.conf reads as follows:

```
...
ServerName www.mydomain.com:80
DocumentRoot "/home/somewhere/www"

NameVirtualHost <IP A>:80

<VirtualHost <IP A> >
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain
    DocumentRoot /home/somewhere/www/admin
    ServerName admin.mydomain.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, if I type `www.mydomain.com` or `admin.mydomain.com` I get the same page, i.e. the main server.
The nslookup command shows that both `www.mydomain.com` and `admin.mydomain.com` point to IP A.
Any help?

Comment: It looks like English is not your first language, so let me help you say that better: My site has one IP with two DNS A records (www.mydomain.com and admin.mydomain.com) pointing at the same IP address.  My apache httpd.conf is as follows:  (You might want to change the question to be more specific:  "How do I debug Apache VirtualHosts when they don't work?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this with two different VHost:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/docs/www"
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/www-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/www-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/usr/local/docs/admin"
        ServerName admin.mydomain.com
        ErrorLog "/var/log/admin-error_log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/admin-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why it works? Shall we always omit the IP address ?

Comment: There is three ways to manage VHost, by IP, by Name or by port. If you  want to manage it with names, then you put *:80 so you accept any IP on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of "apachectl -S"?  When I need to debug VirtualHosts this is the first command I use.  It tell me what the configuration looks like to Apache.

I generally use one VirtualHost for each host, and let the main site (non-virtual) go to a page that says, "If you see this, something is wrong."

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
        ...
        ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName admin.mydomain.com
        ...
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I did your command: no problem is shown

Comment: Apache searches the list in order. If you pretend to be Apache, what would a request for "admin.mydomain.com" match?  What would "www.mydomain.com" match?